# I am trying to add a PictureBox dynamically to a TableLayoutPanel but it's not filling the selected cell

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, tablelayoutpanel

I use this part of code to add the picture but it's half the cell...and still it's not working.

```
PictureBox pB = new PictureBox {
  Size = MaximumSize,
  Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
  BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
};

OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
  string path = ofd.FileName;
  pB.Image = new Bitmap(path);
}

tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pB, x-1, y-1);
Control control = tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(x - 1, y - 1);
control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
control.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Comment: Dock-filling a picturebox is not often correct.  It only looks somewhat decently when the image is a texture with few details.  But then you'd never use a TableLayoutPanel, you'd stitch the image together yourself.  Consider that you need the SizeMode property the way it is already set.  A FlowLayoutPanel could look marginally better.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the **two** images a `PictureBox` can have:

- The `Image` is the main one with all sorts of capabilties
- The `BackgroundImage` is below it and can be use for just that: A background.

You want to set the layout for the `Image`; it is called [`SizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
PictureBox pB = new PictureBox
{
    Size = MaximumSize,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
};
```

Not sure where and how you set `x` and `y` but you should see the full image now, albeit more or less stretched.

And you don't need to set the `SizeMode` or `Docking` again at the end..